# Ubuntu 11.10 Download and install problems

Tags: 11.10, downloads

I m having lot of problems in my newly install ( also in fresh installed copy ) of ubuntu 11.10

whenever i try to download any software the download stuck at certain point always
e.g. teamviewer 14.4 mb, google chrome 26.7 mb.

if i tried
sudo apt-get- upgrade
it will stuck at [waiting for headers]

same happens with 
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
install & download...

i can't determine the problem.

i tried switching server from India to main server still the problem continues.....

can someone please solve this problem

Comment: Have you checked you Internet connection?

Comment: can you post your **lspci**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the same problem in 11.04. Upgrading to 12.04 corrected the problem. Try installing the updates.

Answer (score 0):

To speed up downloading of updates you can do the following:

Go to Ubuntu Software Center > `Edit` > `Software Sources` or (update Manager > settings) and from Download from drop down menu choose `Other` then on the next window choose Select `Best Server` and wait for it to pick the best server for you, then run `sudo apt-get update` again.

Comment: my connection speed is 1mbps works fine for me never drops and my select best server process stuck too :( before everything was working fine i m having problem since 2 days only :(

download always stuck certain points in some softwares only :(

Comment: i m totally unable to download packages in mb even in updates :(